# How do I redirect my Prestashop home page to another URL or page on my website?

Tags: redirect, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-modules

I have a website where I installed Prestahop on a /shop directory but will want to redirect the homepage to the main homepage while other product pages function normal without using a module and without redirecting all pages to the new URL.

EG. I want to change example.com/shop to examplae.com while other pages like example.com/shop/category/product1 work normal.

Answer (score 1):

> I posted the question because there seem to be very little resources
>   on this topic as most answers I got while researching are eighter directing users to buy
>   modules or to do a general redirect.

It worked for me. In my case, I changed the home page to another URL which is mine. Other product pages still work normal. To do that, go to **controllers/front/IndexController.php** and change add the following code somewhere in the **initContent function**.

```
Tools::redirect('http://newwebsiteurl.com/');
```

That is you will delete all the contents in the function below

```
{
    parent::initContent();
    $this->addJS(_THEME_JS_DIR_.'index.js');

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array('HOOK_HOME' => Hook::exec('displayHome'),
        'HOOK_HOME_TAB' => Hook::exec('displayHomeTab'),
        'HOOK_HOME_TAB_CONTENT' => Hook::exec('displayHomeTabContent')
    ));
    $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'index.tpl');
}
```

and replace it with something like this:

```
 {
    parent::initContent();

    Tools::redirect('http://newwebsiteurl.com/');

}
```

It worked for me on my website [Soup Embassy](https://mysoupembassy.com) and I hope does for you too. If you check the URL on [Soup Category](http://mysoupembassy.com/buy-online/13-where-to-buy-soup-online) here, you will see that it is in a directory /buy-online/ and when you click on the home link or logo, it will redirect you to a URL without the extension. I hope you find this helpful.